# Is it possible to associate two models without "belongs_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

Suppose we have two models : Robot and Human.

Is it possible to have one of the followings associations ?

```rb
Robot has_one Human and Human has_one Robot
Robot has_one Human and Human has_many Robots
```

And in which cases must I have `t.integer :robot_id` in my human migration file, or `t.integer :human_id` in my robot migration file ?

Comment: Have you tried? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be looking for [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).  If I read your question right, it'll do exactly what you have in mind.

You'll need a join table to make it work, but that's pretty straightforward.  Cheers!